# How to sscanf this string?: "+CPMS: \"ME\",18,255,\"ME\",18,255,\"ME\",18,255"

Tags: scanf

So, I'm developing an application in C and I need to sscanf a string.

+CPMS: \"ME\",18,255,\"ME\",18,255,\"ME\",18,255

I need to get the number between the first and second commas, 18 in this example, but it can be from 0 to 255.

I'm trying to create the placeholder to get this but I can't seem to make it work.

I've tried lots of thing, but I can't understand why:

sscanf(pointer, "+CPMS: \"%*s\",%d", &intPointer);

doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm going to answer my own question.

sscanf(pointer, "+CPMS: \"%***2**s\",%d", &intPointer);

It looks like I needed to put the number of characters to ignore.

Hope it help someone else.